# Java custom optional values for constructor

Tags: java, constructor

This code is pretty much what I want to do:

```
import java.util.Random;    

public class TestClass {
  protected int testVarA;
  protected int testVarB;

  public TestClass() {
    Random r = new Random();
    this(r.nextInt(),r.nextInt());
  }

  public TestClass(int testVarA, int testVarB) {
    this.testVarA = startTestVarA;
    this.testVarB = startTestVarB;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't compile, since the `this()` statement has to be at the beggining of the function. I could do something like

```
this((new Random()).getNextInt(),(new Random()).getNextInt())
```

But that feels very improper. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use move you complex initialization logic to a separate method:

```
  public TestClass() {
    Random r = new Random();
    init(r.nextInt(),r.nextInt());
  }

  public TestClass(int testVarA, int testVarB) {
    init(testVarA, testVarB)
  }

  private void init(int testVarA, int testVarB) {
    this.testVarA = startTestVarA;
    this.testVarB = startTestVarB;
  }
```

This is more generic solution than just having `Random` as a field. `Random` field works in this particular case since all of the instances of the class can share it without any side-effects, but if you wanted to have something which is not thread-safe as an initializer, this might become a problem. Not even talking about the static field not being eligible for garbage collection. *EVER*

Answer (score 2):

I would create your `Random` object as a `static final` variable outside of any constructors, so that you can reference it in the first line of your no-arg constructor.

```
private static final Random r = new Random();

public TestClass() {
  this(r.nextInt(),r.nextInt());
}
```

This way, you only need one `Random` object, and it's initialized before the constructor's first line.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the Random object, you did not define startTestVarA and startTestVarB.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this?

```
import java.util.Random;    

public class TestClass {
  protected int testVarA;
  protected int testVarB;
  private static Random r = new Random();

  public TestClass() {
    this(r.nextInt(),r.nextInt());
  }

  public TestClass(int testVarA, int testVarB) {
    this.testVarA = testVarA;
    this.testVarB = testVarB;
  }
}
```